To know PowerShell Script to compare timestamp of two directories of WinScp
I am new to PowerShell scripting and we have a problem statement to compare timestamp of files from two directories of WinScp. We know that winscp.net assembly support PowerShell script hence would like to know any sample script for same.
Below is the scenario:

Take input from user to know which file path to be compared
Take input from user to know the file names which is to be compared
compare timestamp and  show the result of comparison.

I would like to get help in scripting or sample script on similar note to resolve our problem statement.
Here we first tried making connection with server , however we are getting error regarding host key algorithm.
Below is the sample code:
try
{
  # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
  Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

  # Setup session options
  $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = "example.com"
    UserName = "user"
    Password = "mypassword"
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxx..."
  }

  $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

  try
  {
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # code for comparing timestamp
  }
  finally
  {
    # Disconnect, clean up
    $session.Dispose()
  }

  exit 0
}
catch
{
  Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
  exit 1
}

We are getting error like:

Couldn't agree a key host algorithm (available rsa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256)

Winscp version is 6.3.1

you are using the wrong key fingerprint. It's pretty explicit: you are sending a rsa 2048 while the host uses only 512 and 256

So you have problem with connecting/host key, not with comparing timestamps. Moreover, you have already asked this question on WinSCP support forum, where I've asked you for additional details. Instead of providing them, you have re-posted your question here, in even more confusing way.
